# Windows 8 Member of Domain greyed out and unselectable

Tags: windows-8

I want to add my windows 8 machine to a domain, but the option "Member of"  is greyed out and unselectable.What to do in this case?

Comment: You kind of need to be more specific on here. Is it the only Win8 machine? What make and model is it? What version of domain software are you using? Is there any additional information if you right click and press properties?

Comment: Yes, It's the only 8 machine that I have in the network. It's the Asus Machine and I'm using windows server 2008

Comment: What version of Windows 8 Home/Pro/Enterprise?

Comment: It's the Home version of windows 8

Comment: You cannot join a domain with Home edition.

Comment: You mean Just Pro and entreprise versions are supported?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you will need to upgrade for that feature :(

Comment: Once Upgraded, The option 'Member of ' is enabled?

Comment: @hmdw - All Windows 8.x Professional and Windows 8.x Enterprise machines can join a domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows 8 Basic edition, it will not be able to join the domain.

[image]

Fortunately, it's easy to upgrade without reinstalling Windows though with **add features**.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx